# AJAX no envia data a PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

es mi primera vez usando AJAX, por mas ejemplos que pongo en practica, no logro hacer que AJAX envíe a PHP una variable, en cambio si se comunica con el archivo PHP, pero cuando doy `alert(data);` me sale el html de mi pagina .php, en lugar de mostrarme la variable que le pase como parámetro.

Este es el puro AJAX

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: 'IPE.php',
    data: { textValue : textValue }, //intentando pasar textValue que deberia valer 10:10 pero me da el html de ipe.php
    success: function(data){
    alert(data);//html ipe.php
    alert(textValue);//si vale 10:10
}
```

Que esta dentro de este dialogo (dialogo.js)

```
 $(function () {
          $('#myTextBox').mask('00:00');
          //Set up the dialog box
          $("#myDialog").dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              modal: true,
              title: "Escriba en formato HH:mm",
              buttons: {
                  'Agregar': function () {
                      var textValue = $('#myTextBox').val();// valor 10:10
                      var validTime = textValue.match(/^([0-9]*):[0-5][0-9]$/);
                      if (!validTime) {
                          alert('El formato ingresado no es correcto');
                      } else {
                        alert(textValue);
                          $.ajax(
                          {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'IPE.php',
                            data: { textValue : textValue }, //intentando pasar textValue que deberia valer 10:10 pero me da el html de ipe.php
                            success: function(data){
                            alert(data);//html ipe.php
                            alert(textValue);//si vale 10:10
                          }
                          });
                          $(this).dialog('close');
                          $('#myTextBox').val("");
                      }
                      //Now you have the value of the textbox, you can do something with it, maybe an AJAX call to your server!
                  },
                  'Cancelar': function () {
                      $(this).dialog('close');
                      $('#myTextBox').val("");
                  }
              }
          });
          //Open the dialog box when the button is clicked.
          $('#clickMe').click(function () {
              $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
          });
      });
```

Este es el html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>IPE (Indisponibilidad de Planta de Emergencia).</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<script src="dialogo.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div style="left: 82.5%; top:3%; position: absolute;">
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Año..">
    <div id="myDialog">
      <input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
      <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

La parte de (IPE.php) que debe obtener la data de AJAX

```
if(isset($_POST['textValue'])) //
{
    $nuevo_registro = $_POST['textValue'];
    echo $nuevo_registro;
}
```

Cabe destacar que el html esta dentro de IPE.php

Comment: ¿El codigo de IPE.php esta completo aqui? ¿como es que el html esta dentro de IPE.php?

Comment: No esta completo, pero ese codigo si esta dentro de las etiquetas de php.

Comment: tienes otro contenido dentro de tu IPE.php? o es solo para recibir los datos mediante ajax?

Comment: Si, IPE.php lee un xml, crea una tabla en base a ello (el contenido del xml son registros de tiempo mensuales), lo que pretendo es que AJAX le mande a IPE.php por ejemplo "10:10" y en PHP sumar ese "10:10" al registro actual XML del mes, y ya teniendo el resultado, insertarlo en el XML. A manera de prueba de que tengo la variable del lado de PHP es el echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que **lo estas haciendo bien.** Como mencionas en tu pregunta, al tratar de visualizar lo que el servidor esta respondiendo ves todo el HTML de la página `IPE.php` en vez de la respuesta que deberia generar `echo $nuevo_registro`. Esto ya de por si es  una constancia de que `$.ajax()` esta funcionando.

Lo que sucede es que la funcion `$.ajax()` de JQuery hace una petición HTTP formal al servidor y este devuelve exactamente lo que le estan pidiendo. De manera que, el servidor ejecuta el codigo PHP de la página y la sirve a la petición, por lo que devuelve la página completa, es decir, todo el HTML que este en `IPE.php`.

Lo que te recomiendo es que pruebes solo codigo PHP en tu archivo `IPE.php`. Imagina que tu `IPE.php` se viera asi:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['textValue'])) //
{
    $nuevo_registro = $_POST['textValue'];
    echo $nuevo_registro;
}
?>
```

De esta forma obtendras como respuesta el resultado del `echo`. Puedes ver mas informacion de `$.ajax()` en este [enlace](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Al final, lo que estoy tratando de explicar es que una petición HTTP formal siempre devuelve todo el HTML que esta en el archivo al que estas haciendo la petición, esa es la idea detras de un servidor web. Así que lo único que tienes que controlar es que tu archivo al que le estas haciendo la petición tenga únicamente lo que quieres ver y no HTML extra.

P.D. La respuesta de [sioesi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88331/ajax-no-envia-data-a-php/88343#88345) tambien te puede ayudar, aunque según la documentación no es completamente indispensable. Saludos!

Comment: Oh ya, yo estoy "necio" con el echo, por que intuía que era una forma correcta de demostrar que ya tenia la variable de lado de php, el fin no es hacer un echo, si no que IPE.php obtenga el string "99:59", por ejemplo, para que lo sume a otra hora ya registrada. Pero aun no entiendo como hacer esto.

Comment: El fin no es mostrar el "99:59", si no procesarlo (sumarlo a otra hora) que obtengo leyendo un XML, y despues el resultado insertarlo al XML, y todo eso esta en IPE.php, por eso lo necesito en IPE.php

Comment: Entiendo y por eso te digo que lo estas haciendo bien. Pienso que lo que te esta confundiendo es ver todo el html en el alert cuando solo deberias ver tu variable que esta en el echo y mi respuesta explica porque esta pasando esto. Asi que, al final si estas mandando la info del lado de PHP es solo que ver el html en el alert te esta confundiendo. Independientemente de lo que hagas con el XML la peticion AJAX esta funcionando bien.

Comment: Para que quizas salgas de tu duda, prueba quitar todo el HTML de tu archivo y dejar solo el codigo PHP dentro de sus respectivas etiquetas y veras a que me refiero.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esas muy confundido

En tu Ajax tiene el parametro data, donde envías tus variables la función success: se ejecuta una vez que el Ajax logro comunicarse con el servidor y este le ha contestado, por eso recibe como entrada la respuesta del servidor en este caso la respuesta del archivo PHP que estas llamando, no te confundas data es la propiedad donde puedes enviar las variables y en el success le he cambiado el nombre para que no te confundas. Espero haberme dado a entender.

Voy a comentar el código para tratar de ser más claro.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST", //Método por el cual se hará la petición
    url: 'IPE.php', //Dirección del archivo solicitado 
    data: { textValue : textValue }, //Envió de variables
    //Aquí termina el envio
    //Apartir de aquí se recibe la respuesta de IPE.php
    success: function(respuestaservidor){//Si el archivo que llamamos se ejecuto sin problemas nos va a responder respuestaservidor es un parametro de entrada lo puedes llamar como quieras y este contiene la respuesta de IPE.php
    alert(respuestaservidor);//html ipe.php
}
```

Comment: Si, es que es mi primera vez usando AJAX, entonces como podria pasar 
`var textValue = $('#myTextBox').val();// valor 10:10` mediante AJAX a PHP? debo modificar el success ?

Comment: Porque, si entonces que me mostrara el html en respuesta, es señal de que si se comunico con IPE.php, entonces PHP no esta recibiendo la variable, por que no se muestra el echo.

Answer (score 0):

Como estas enviando un Object `{ },` la estructura correcta es :

```
data: { "textValue" : textValue }
```

Y en el PHP tal como lo estas recibiendo

```
$_POST['textValue'];
```

Lo demas, esta todo correcto.

Comment: Hice los cambios, pero en IPE.php sigue sin mostrar el echo.

Comment: agrega un `exit()` despues de tu echo

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría lo siguiente:

1: separa los archivos uno con el HTML y otro com el PHP para que no imprimas el html en el mismo archivo

2: Si lo quieres en un mismo archivo puedes usar una condicional `if(isset($_POST['textValue'])) { ... } else { // TODO TU HTML}`

3: Lo más recomendable es usar `exit();`

`<?php
if(isset($_POST['textValue']))
{
    $nuevo_registro = $_POST['textValue'];
    echo $nuevo_registro;
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...`